# Particle systems disappearing after 'Convert To Mesh'

Tags: particles, hair

I have created hair on my model using the particle system. I want to convert all the hair particles strands into meshes.

The issue I am having is that upon converting ONE particle group to a mesh, All other groups disappear from the modifier stack. This means that I can not convert them into meshes. How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why blender is doing this is that after clicking *convert to mesh*, the focus becomes your selection on the **new hair mesh.**

Because your selection is on the hair mesh which doesn't actually have any modifiers applied to it, your modifier stack shows nothing in it.

Thus, what you need to do is

1. click on your hair object.
2. convert to mesh.
3. click BACK onto your hair object.
4. then convert to mesh the next hair group
5. repeat.

This will give give you the functionality you desire.

[image]